# Borland Warning 8092

Tags: c++, c++builder

Regarding the following C++ code,

```
LengthAlphabeticalSort lengthAlphabeticalSort;
outputList.sort(lengthAlphabeticalSort); // causes borland 8092 error, guaranteed stable_sort.

class LengthAlphabeticalSort
{
    public:
        bool operator() (std::string str1, std::string str2)
        {
            if(str1.length() < str2.length())
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
};
```

I get a warning when compiling with the borland compiler:

Warning W8092 worder.cpp 138: template argument _Pr3 passed to 'sort' is not an
iterator: random iterator required in function Worder::CommonWords(const Worder
&) const
Turbo Incremental Link 5.69 Copyright (c) 1997-2005 Borland

Can anybody tell me how to fix this problem? It compiles cleanly with VS2010 and gnu

Comment: typedef std::list<std::string> StringList;

it is of type std::list<std::string>

Comment: Can you confirm that the line you've marked is definitely the line in the warning message (worder.cpp, line 138)?

Comment: Yes, it is. This is also the only place where I call sort with a functor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the `sort` member function on a `std::list` does take a binary functor like yours, so from looking at your posted code, I'd say your compiler is wrong.

However, the error message you posted puzzles me:

```
random iterator required in function Worder::CommonWords(const Worder &) const
```

Why is it saying that a random iterator is required in `CommonWords`? Is `CommonWords` the function from which `sort` is called?

Comment: Yes, the sort is called in CommonWords.

Comment: I guess its a compiler error, pity nobody has a more definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I find the name `LengthAlphabeticalSort` confusing because the sort is purely by length, not by something alphabetical. Also, you should pass strings by reference-to-const, and the if-else is superfluous:

```
struct ByLength
{
    bool operator()(const std::string& a, const std::string& b)
    {
        return a.length() < b.length();
    }
};
```

> The initial list is guaranteed to be in alphabetical order.

Does that mean you are sorting twice, first alphabetical, then by length? I think it's better practice to sort only once with an adequate predicate:

```
struct FirstByLengthThenAlphabetical
{
    bool operator()(const std::string& a, const std::string& b)
    {
        if (a.length() < b.length()) return true;
        if (b.length() < a.length()) return false;
        return a < b;
    }
};
```

Comment: The initial list is guaranteed to be in alphabetical order. Hence, as list.sort() is guaranteed to be a stable sort, just sorting by length will give a sort that is by length and then, if the same length, in alphabetical order hence the naming convention.

passing by reference and the superfluous if-else is something I overlooked. +1

Comment: theres a good reason why its already alphabetical. I am calling set_intersection on two sets and outputting the result to a list. Hence the list is always alphabetical in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I came across this problem while doing some compilation under an older version of Borland as well (this issue may be fixed in more recent versions). I was able to experiment and discover that it seems Borland does a lookup by function name to see if you might be calling an stl algorithm. Because of this, anything named exactly the same as an stl algorithm will check to see if you are passing the proper iterator type into the function.

This is messy, because sort is `std::sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last)` algorithm, but sort is also a `std::list::sort(Compare comp)` method. Unfortunately, this strikes me as a very egregious compiler error, that is entirely dependent on the name of the function/method.

I don't know what the workaround would be for std::list or other containers that have methods named the same as algorithms, but the best solution would be to ignore the warning for that particular issue by using the command-line option: `-w-8092`